# When clicking the Submit button on my web form, how come the validation errors for the Input fields display, even when these fields have values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, form-submit

When testing my web form that was built using HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, PHP and jQuery, the first thing I do is click the Submit button. When I do this, the text-danger errors display below the Input and Text Area fields as expected since the fields are empty. If I add a value in the Input field "Name" and click the Submit button again, the text-danger field continues to display below the Name field. The same goes when I try the same thing for the Email and Security Check fields.

When I add a value in the Message Text Area field, the text-danger error for the message field disappears along with the other errors. The message field needs to have a value in order for the errors for all of the fields to disappear.

How should I set up my jQuery so that once a value is added to a field and I click the Submit button to test, the text-danger error for that specific field no longer displays?

**HTML and jQuery Code**

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <form method="post" action="index.php" class="form-horizontal">
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
           <p class="text-danger">You need to enter a name value</p>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="your@email.com" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
           <p class="text-danger">You need to enter a valid email</p>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
           <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="4" class="form-control"><?php echo $message;?></textarea>
           <p class="text-danger">You need to enter a message</p>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <label for="secCheck" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
           <?php echo $_SESSION["a"] .'+'.$_SESSION["b"];?>
           </label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input type="text" id="secCheck" name="secCheck" class="form-control">
           <p class="text-danger">Answer the question above</p>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2"> 
             <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" id="submit" name="submit">
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2"> 
             <?php echo $result; ?>
          </div>
         </div
      </form>   
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

 $('form').on('submit',function(){
     $(".text-danger").hide();
     var holderValue = false;
     $(this).find('input[type!="hidden"]').each(function(){

        if(!$(this).val()){holderValue=true; $(this).parent().find(".text-danger").show();}
     })
     if(!$("#message").val()){holderValue=true; $(this).parent().find(".text-danger").show();};

     if(holderValue){return false;}
     // event.preventDefault();
     // console.log('form submitted');   
     })


$("input").on("change paste keyup", function() {
  if($(this).val()){
 $(this).parent().find(".text-danger").hide();
} 
});

$("textarea").on("change paste keyup", function() {
  if($(this).val()){
 $(this).parent().find(".text-danger").hide();
} 
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Bootstrap Custom Form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#custom-styles)

There are a couple of key Bootstrap attributes and classes needed for custom validation:

#### HTML

> - `<form ...` **novalidate**`>`
> - All `<input ...` **required**`>`
> - Remove all <del>`<p class='danger-text'>...`</del>
> - Replace the previous with `<aside class='`**invalid-feedback**`'>`

Also the tags have been changed from `<div>` to a more semantic tag, but it isn't required. The layout has been changed as well -- originally the layout had only one `.row` which now has several `.form-row`s (not sure if that was intentional or not, but it looks better when using `.form-control`).

---

#### jQuery

> - On each `.form-control` ...
>     `$('.form-control').each(function() {...`
> - ...if the current `.form-control` is invalid...
>     `if ($(this).is(':invalid')) {...`
> - ...stop the  from submitting and show the invalid message...
>     `e.preventDefault();`
>       `$(this).next('.invalid-feedback').show();...`
> - ...otherwise hide the invalid message if need be.
>     `} else {`
>       `$(this).next('.invalid-feedback').hide();`
>     `}`

---

### Demo

```js
$('.invalid-feedback').hide();
$('#main').on('submit', function(e) {
  $('.form-control').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':invalid')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).next('.invalid-feedback').show();
    } else {
      $(this).next('.invalid-feedback').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<main class="container">
  <form id='main' class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="index.php" novalidate>

    <section class="form-row">
      <fieldset class="form-group col-sm-10">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">
          Name
        </label>
        <input id="name" name="name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
        <aside class="invalid-feedback">
          You need to enter your name.
        </aside>
      </fieldset>
    </section>

    <section class="form-row">
      <fieldset class="form-group col-sm-10">
        <label for="email" class="control-label">
          Email
        </label>
        <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="your@email.com" required>
        <aside class="invalid-feedback">
          You need to enter your email.
        </aside>
      </fieldset>
    </section>

    <section class="form-row">
      <fieldset class="form-group col-sm-10">
        <label for="message" class="control-label">
          Message
        </label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="4" required></textarea>
        <aside class="invalid-feedback">
          You need to enter a message.
        </aside>
      </fieldset>
    </section>

    <section class="form-row">
      <fieldset class="form-group col-sm-10">
        <label for="secCheck" class="control-label">
        </label>
        <input id="secCheck" name="secCheck" class="form-control" type="text" required>
        <aside class="invalid-feedback">
          Answer the security question above.
        </aside>
      </fieldset>
    </section>

    <section class="form-row">
      <fieldset class="form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" type="submit" value="Send">
      </fieldset>
    </section>

    <section class="form-row">
      <fieldset class="form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <output id='result'></output>
      </fieldset>
    </section>

  </form>
</main>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I tested everything out on my own website, and everything worked perfectly! Your breakdown of the jQuery code was great to see too and easy to follow.